How to merge input variables into a single list field in pydantic?
I have input data ( a csv file) that has columns that are named like item1, item2, item3
I would like to have a field in my pydantic model called 'items' that collects all the item# input variables into a list without having to list each item# as a field explicitly.
So instead of this
class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    item1: str
    item2: str
    item3: str
...

I want something like this
class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    items: List[str]

Is there some way to do this easily? perhaps with aliases or computed fields? I'm trying to work with pydantic instead of hacking around it.
I tried looking into the docs but I couldn't find anything that does what I want.

If you want to define the fields when you're loading the csv file, you have no other choice than creating the model dynamically. But in that case you don't have benefits from static type checkers like mypy of course.
